# Printing: Different pages from different feeds (pdf)

Tags: linux, pdf, printing

I've got a pdf document and want to print it about 100 times with a Kyocera fs 4020dn printer. I'd like to have the first page on colored paper.

Is it possible to tell the printer to take the first page from manual feed and the remaining pages from the regular cassette?

I know there are possibilities to do this in Word or OO but I don't know how to solve this for pdf files.

I'm using Linux (Kbuntu).

Comment: If you stick just one page into the manual feed, then print, won't it take that first sheet and pull the rest from whats available (the bin)?

Comment: You're right but I want to print the document about 100 times. Sorry, my question was unclear in this point...

Comment: if it were Windows: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6iXuU4b5mh4 :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem with a shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh
i=1
while [ $i -le <number of printouts> ]
do
  lp -o media=<name of feed> <file> -P 1
  lp <file> -P 2-<number of pages>
  i=`expr $i + 1`
done
```