# Printing pages to different feeds (pdf) WINDOWS

Tags: windows, printing, batch-file, feed

We are currently sending out letters that print:

1. Letter on letter-head (customized for recipient)
2. Instructions on regular paper (customized for recipient)

These letters are all sent automatically in a PDF, so the PDF pages look something like:

1. Receipt 1's Letter
2. Receipt 1's Instructions
3. Receipt 2's Letter
4. Receipt 2's Instructions
5. etc...

We are sending these out daily (and will usually send to roughly 20+ recipients) and I would like to know if there is a way to print the Letters and the Instructions to separate feeds on a printer.  It might be okay in the long run to continue printing 'odd/even' pages to separate feeds, but it's possible that more pages will be added, killing the odd/even method. That and I want to make this as simple and fast as possible for those will be doing the actual printing.

---

**Potential Solution:**

I found this post: [Printing: Different pages from different feeds (pdf)](https://superuser.com/questions/473827/printing-different-pages-from-different-feeds-pdf).
This is similar to the solution I need, but uses shell scripts.  I am going to attempt to see if I can learn batch files and get them to do something to the shell script.  But this needs to be something a person with enough-to-get-by computer-knowledge could use (maybe there is a program that does something similar?).

If anyone has

- a better solution (some known software perhaps)
- a batch file one is willing to share
- some info on printing from different feeds using batch files
- other useful information

it would be appreciated to have/hear.

Comment: FYI, I don't think you'll be able to port the linux solution to Windows, as I don't know of any way to print from the command line and specify a feed/tray.  I researched this a bit, but neither the native `print.exe`, nor any of the PDF utilities I looked at support a tray option from the command line.

Comment: Hm, I'll have to look into it more then.  Thanks for the info!

Comment: search for Ricoh Print&Share and also tutorial videos. Not that hard to do with P&S.